# expect to send answers unknown number of times in Unix

Tags: unix, expect

I am writing a wrapper script for a ruby script.
My requirement is whenever to send y as an input unknown number of times as a interactive part.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "./rubyScript"

while(true){

    # I am unaware of how many times this interactive part can come

    expect "*(y/n)" 

    send "y\r"

    interact

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `while`, `exp_continue` can be used which is much efficient though.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn "./rubyScript"
expect { 
        "*(y/n)" { send "y\r";exp_continue; }
        timeout { break }
    }
}
```

The command `exp_continue` allows expect itself to continue executing rather than returning as it normally would. This is useful for avoiding explicit loops or repeated expect statements.

By default, `exp_continue` resets the timeout timer.  The timer is not restarted, if `exp_continue` is called with the `-continue_timer` flag.

Comment: just I am curious to know what if we want to run a script which requires sudo access such as     #!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn "sudo -u userName /abc/rubyScript"
expect { 
        "*(y/n)" { send "y\r";exp_continue; }
        timeout { break }
    }
}   In that case we get an error "no such file or directory"

Comment: You should use `eval` before the spawn command such as `eval  spawn sudo -u userName /abc/rubyScript`

Comment: My script first asks for password which I am giving manually then after half an hour or so it asks for (y/n) and then it asks for (y/n) many times(unknown) so what shall be the timeout time.

Comment: Based on your ruby script, you can decide the `timeout` value. Since you are saying that it takes half an hour, you can set it to 1800. (60*30=1800s)

Comment: I tried to set timeout to -1 but that is also of no help.

Comment: You should not use -1 here. By setting timeout to -1, you are making `expect` to wait for it indefinitely. Since you are using `exp_continue`, it will keep on stuck in that `(y/n)` string and there wont be any timeout at all. Set it to some maximum reasonable amount. (3600 = 1 hour)

Comment: Thanks for discussing over it. When I am no setting the timeout my ruby script starts running in 10 seconds , when I am setting timeout to 20 my ruby script starts running in 20 seconds but till the time it comes to (y/n) I have give input as y manually. If I am setting the timeout to 3600, my ruby script is not at all running.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to catch the `timeout` event from the `expect` statement. When `expect` has failed to find the `(y/n)` prompt within the specified timeout, we can assume that application is ready to become interactive.

For example (untested, do not have `expect` at hand):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
spawn "./rubyScript"
while {1} {
    expect { 
        "*(y/n)" { send "y\r" }
        timeout { break }
    }
}
interact
```

Send `y` if `(y/n)` prompt. If no prompt was seen - break the loop and  `interact`.

Comment: Getting same error which I was getting earlier :-----                 spawn ./rubyScript
invalid command name "while(1){"
    while executing
"while(1){"
    (file “./rubyScript line 6)

Comment: Use `{}` instead of `()`. Also, you should have a space between braces like `while {1} {`